# How to store various types as one type in C++?

Tags: c++11, types

My C++ is a bit rusty nowadays so stupid question -- how to store various types as one type?

What I have is type info (not in C++ sense) and data itself. The first one is just an `enum`, data can be `int`, or `vector<string>`. I have to store them in one `vector<T>` -- and the question is what should be `T`? `void*`?

Later based on my `enum` type I can down- or up-cast the data, load it, save it, pass it, no problem here.

In C# it would be `object`, but C++ does not have common root type, and also my types do not have common root type.

I use C++11.

Comment: Inherit from a base class (e.g., `class B`) and use dynamic polymorphism (e.g., `vector<B*>`).

Comment: @40two, impossible, you cannot redefine int. Besides, I don't define types, I just receive data, all I have to do is store them in container.

Comment: How about e.g. [Boost any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/any.html)?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, looks great. Can you please post a regular answer so I can accept it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a bounded list of known types (it looks like you do if the only data types are `int` and `vector<string>`, a good bet would be to use a [Boost Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/variant/).

---

Comment: Ha! Thank you. In my case it is even better than boost any, because indeed I have finite, small and known in advance set of types.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably do it with [Boost Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/any.html).